# Show that $ 1+\|x + y\| \geq \frac{1+\|x\|}{1+\|y\|}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the next equation holds:

$$
    1+\|x + y\| \geq \frac{1+\|x\|}{1+\|y\|}
$$

I already proved the following, which is supposed to be helpful.
$$
    1+\|x+y\| \leq (1+\|x\|)(1+\|y\|)
$$

The attempts so far where not very fruitful, any hint or answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You proved
$$
1+||z||\leq (1+||z-y||)(1+||y||).
$$
Now let $z=-x$, then
$$
1+||x||=1+||-x||=1+||z||\leq(1+||-x-y||)(1+||y||)=(1+||x+y||)(1+||y||).
$$
Dividing both sides by $(1+||y||)$ yields the desired result.

Comment: Really fast, applause!